# Is there any easy way of a generic type is subtype of another type in python or mypy?

Tags: python, generics, mypy

I want to explore the subtyping relations with generics, for simple classes I can use

```
issubclass(bool, int) # True
```

But for generics I get an error

```
issubclass(list[bool], list[int])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: issubclass() argument 2 cannot be a parameterized generic
```

Is there any interactive way of doing this?

Comment: You can `typing.get_origin` and assume you already know what to do later:) Basically `issubclass(T, get_origin(U) or U)` should work both for parametrized and non-parametrized `U`. First argument can remain subscripted.